# Threads and clocked threads in SystemC

Tags: while-loop, systemc

While reading about the threads in SystemC, it is said that `while(true)` loop must be used inside the functions. Why is it so?

Can you please see the example code given below and explain why the while loop is used for threads and `wait()` command is used along with the loop:

```
 1 //-----------------------------------------------------
  2 // This is my second Systemc Example
  3 // Design Name : first_counter
  4 // File Name : first_counter.cpp
  5 // Function : This is a 4 bit up-counter with
  6 // Synchronous active high reset and
  7 // with active high enable signal
  8 //-----------------------------------------------------
  9 #include "systemc.h"
 10 
 11 SC_MODULE (first_counter) {
 12   sc_in_clk     clock ;      // Clock input of the design
 13   sc_in<bool>   reset ;      // active high, synchronous Reset input
 14   sc_in<bool>   enable;      // Active high enable signal for counter
 15   sc_out<sc_uint<4> > counter_out; // 4 bit vector output of the counter
 16 
 17   //------------Local Variables Here---------------------
 18   sc_uint<4>    count;
 19 
 20   //------------Code Starts Here-------------------------
 21   // Below function implements actual counter logic
 22   void incr_count () {
 23     // For threads, we need to have while true loop
 24     while (true) { 
 25       // Wait for the event in sensitivity list to occure
 26       // In this example - positive edge of clock
 27       wait();
 28       if (reset.read() == 1) {
 29         count =  0;
 30         counter_out.write(count);
 31       // If enable is active, then we increment the counter
 32       } else if (enable.read() == 1) {
 33         count = count + 1;
 34         counter_out.write(count);
 35       }
 36     }
 37   } // End of function incr_count
 38 
 39   // Below functions prints value of count when ever it changes
 40   void print_count () {
 41     while (true) {
 42       wait();
 43       cout<<"@" << sc_time_stamp() <<
 44         " :: Counter Value "<<counter_out.read()<<endl;
 45     }
 46   }
 47 
 48   // Constructor for the counter
 49   // Since this counter is a positive edge trigged one,
 50   // We trigger the below block with respect to positive
 51   // edge of the clock
 52   SC_CTOR(first_counter) {
 53     // Edge sensitive to clock
 54     SC_THREAD(incr_count);
 55     sensitive << clock.pos();
 56     // Level Sensitive to change in counter output
 57     SC_THREAD(print_count);
 58     sensitive << counter_out;
 59   } // End of Constructor
 60 
 61 }; // End of Module counter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SC_THREAD` or `SC_CTHREAD` should have infinite loop to keep the thread not being terminated. If you don't put `for(;;)` or `while(true)` in the function body, when the execution reaches the end of function scope, the thread is terminated. In such case, your thread will never be waken up by the sensitive list for processing something. Or you can it transform to equivalent `SC_METHOD`, then you can have no infinite loop.

SystemC is using non-preemptive thread, so if you don't use `wait()` to wait for something listed in static or dynamic sensitive list to happen, it causes a infinite execution in your thread. And CPU execution of your process won't get out of the function scope. Such that SystemC kernel won't able to continue to process other methods/threads and events to continue the simulation. And in the event-based simulation, the thread should only be run when the specified condition (events in the sensitive list) occur. So the `wait()` function can wait until the next event occurs and hand over the CPU execution to other threads/methods and SystemC kernel. Next time the event occurs, for example the positive edge of clock, `wait()` statement will return and continue your process.

In your example, your program is waiting for clock's positive edge trigger to increase the counter's value by 1. So, if you don't put `wait()` in your code, then `incr_count` will always increase the counter's value infinitely no matter the clock's status, and it won't stop. By using `wait()`, your thread will be blocked and wait for next clock positive edge trigger.

Answer (score 0):

while(true) --> makes thread infinite, so that it can keep executing when it gets context
wait() --> forces the thread to lose context and allows something else to be executed